# Does this need explicit synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, executor

I have two threads, and I want to make sure I am doing the synchronization correctly on the LinkedBlockingQueue..  Is this correct?  Or is the explicit synchronization on (messageToCommsQueue) not necessary?

Declaration:

```
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<BaseMessage> messagesToCommsQueue;
```

Method one:

```
private void startOperationModeStatusMessageExecutor() {

    ScheduledExecutorService operationModeStatusExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    operationModeStatusExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate((new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ModeStatusMessage commsOperateMsg;
                commsOperateMsg = MessageFactory.getModeStatusMessage(status.ordinal());
            synchronized (messagesToCommsQueue) {
                messagesToCommsQueue.add(commsOperateMsg);
            }
        }

    }), 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Method Two:

```
    Executor commsSenderExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    commsSenderExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (getStatus().equals(ModeStatus.INITIATE) || getStatus().equals(ModeStatus.OPERATE)) {
                BaseMessage m = null;
                try {
                    synchronized (messagesToCommsQueue) {
                        m = messagesToCommsQueue.take();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's not necessary. [JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) says that:

> BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe.